# How do you allocate 25 memory spaces in a list, in Python?

Tags: python, list, loops

In java it would be:
               int Bit_list[] = new int Bit_list [25];

I can get it done with a loop and append like this:

```
Bit_list = ['x']

"""
        loop to make space in memory for Bit_list
"""

a = 0
while  (a != 21):

    appd = 'x'
    Bit_list.append(appd)

    a  += 1
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Other than "why would you", `['x']*25`

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311775/python-create-a-list-with-initial-capacity

Comment: alternative: ['x' for _i in range(25)]

Answer (score 1):

this is one method:

```
lst = 25 * [None]
print(lst)
```