# Python: A list that doesn't get relocated

Tags: python, arrays, list, optimization

I'm trying to optimize an algorithm in Python **purely for fun / curiosity**. I have a list that I'm constantly adding items and removing items from. I know that the way Python lists are implemented, Python will relocate the list in memory for you depending on its size. For example, if you have a list with 10 members, the 10 pointers will be stored consecutively in memory, but there may not be room for 100 consecutive pointers, since another program might be taking a memory block that's in the way. So as you add more members to the list, at some point Python will relocate the entire list to a different place in memory where there's more room for the list to expand.

**I'm curious to know whether there is a custom data structure in Python that behaves like a list, but allows me to avoid the performance cost of doing a relocation.** I'm expecting that this data type will ask me, in advance, how many members I foresee it will have, and then it'll allocate a big contiguous space in memory so it won't need to relocate the list as it slowly grows to the number of members I specified.

(Note: I tried using a Numpy array, but I had to keep a separate "needle" variable that kept the size of the list, and I'm afraid that the overhead of maintaining that needle in Python cost more than the gain.)

Comment: Not going to close this as a dupe yet, but you should see the answer to this similar question that shows that you're optimizing prematurely: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311775/python-create-a-list-with-initial-capacity

Comment: If you're only adding/removing from the ends, [deque](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is an option: "Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction."

Comment: @Anonymous deque is a great option, and currently my algorithm that uses deque is the top performer. Regardless, I'm still curious to get an answer about a non-relocating list.

Comment: Appreciate the highlight on 'purely for fun' so you don't get lots of yelling :). Question - have you been able to measure the performance of this relocation in any way, to give yourself a benchmark? With no reason for thinking this, I thought relocations generally double-d the size of the available slots, giving you `log n` growth. Again - not an answer to your question; just wondering if that's relevant/if you have measured it.

Comment: @dwanderson Haven't measured. That'll be really interesting. I see that the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/311833/76701 has it measured but I wish I had a way to measure it in my algorithm, because maybe it's different there.

Comment: Ah, I was just thinking of a "pre-allocation" a la `items = [None] * size`, but that's represented in that link. Even if it's `log n`, I wouldn't expect `n=10000` to be a great indicator; I'd be mroe intrigued with `n=10**9` or better yet, comparisons across multiple orders of magnitude. +1 internet karma for whoever does that and posts the results

Comment: @dwanderson The problem with pre-allocating is that you can no longer use `len(items)` in the algorithm, you have to keep a needle variable that tracks the length of the list, and that can throw off your measurement. I specified that in the question ;)

Comment: Sounds like you might want a (B-)tree structured list. A little slower but no need for relocation. There is a existing library for it.

Comment: @DanD. I tried it but it's slower :( Possibly there's more overhead because the b-list is split to multiple lists, which is something I don't need.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the curiosity I implemented simple benchmark to test various methods mentioned here. As people predicted the differences are quite small. That said for larger data sets pre-allocating the list and keeping track of the size is faster but this of course is only the case when adding/removing items at the end.

**Benchmark**

```
import time
from collections import deque

def normal(size):
    res = []
    for x in xrange(size):
        res.append(x)

def prealloc(size):
    res = [0] * size
    len = 0 # Separate length tracking
    for x in xrange(size):
        res[len] = x
        len += 1

def deq(size):
    res = deque()
    for x in xrange(size):
        res.append(x)

FUNCS = [
    ['list', normal],
    ['pre-allocate', prealloc],
    ['deque', deq]
]

size = 10
while size <= 10000000:
    print 'size: {0}'.format(size)
    for n, f in FUNCS:
        start = time.clock()
        for i in xrange(30):
            f(size)
        t = time.clock() - start
        print '{}: {}'.format(n, (t / 30))
    size *= 100
    print ''
```

**Results**

```
size: 10
list: 2.13049681786e-06
pre-allocate: 2.03719038788e-06
deque: 2.00608824456e-06

size: 1000
list: 0.000104425446219
pre-allocate: 8.72415120307e-05
deque: 0.000106369330176

size: 100000
list: 0.00984092031242
pre-allocate: 0.00825001457913
deque: 0.0101434508606

size: 10000000
list: 1.23171166758
pre-allocate: 0.876017370547
deque: 1.05051393959
```

Tests were run with Python 2.7.10 on Windows 8.