# Python dictionary dynamic length

Tags: python, dictionary, dynamic

How to dynamically set the length of a Python dictionary (i.e. how to dynamically set the number of key values in a dictionary)

And each value (which will be an integer) of the dictionary should point to a list. This list should could be variable length for each key value of the dictionary.

Comment: Can you show your expected output? And what you've tried so far?

Comment: Python dictionaries are already dynamic. And what would it mean for an integer value to "point to" a list?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you want your dict to have a length of n, you add n elements to the dict. If you want more, you add more. If you want less, you remove some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *"How to dynamically set the length of a Python dictionary (i.e. how to dynamically set the number of **key values** in a dictionary)"*
2. *"And each value (which will be an integer) of the dictionary should point to a list."*

First of all, **key values** above in the first sentence are called simply **keys** in Python. Second, the *things* to which these keys "point" are called **values**. So, your lists are **values**.

To answer your first question: you can't set the length of the dictionary. Instead you simply add key-value pairs to the dictionary (or delete keys) and this is how you *dynamically* control the length of the dictionary.

What you really want, it seems to me (after some head scratching), is a `defaultdict`:

```
In [32]: from collections import defaultdict
    ...: d = defaultdict(list)
    ...: d['first'].append(1)
    ...: print(d['second']) # simply accessing a non-existant key
    ...:                    # creates the default value - an empty list
    ...: print(d)
    ...: 
[]
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'first': [1], 'second': []})
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, you can initialize the dictionary with `None`. See [here](http://For%20the%20first%20part,%20you%20can%20initialize%20the%20dictionary%20with%20%60None%60.%20See%20the%20following:%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311775/python-create-a-list-with-initial-capacity.).

For the second part, dictionaries are already made up of key-value pairs, so if you want your dictionary's integer index to refer to a list, you could do this:

```
 # Initialize your dictionary
 new_dict = dict()

 # Add each list "manually"
 new_dict[0] = ['your', 'list', 'elements'] # 

 # Loop through the available lists and add them to your dictionary
 for i in range(100):
     new_dict[i] = list_of_lists[i]
```